# Create specific WAR file

Tags: ant

In a ANT script, is there a way to include a file from 'environnement' directory into the different war ?

My filesystem tree :

- environnement

  - DEV

    - web.xml
    - log4j.properties
  - INT

    - web.xml
    - log4j.properties
- WebContent

  - WEB-INF

    - web.xml
    - log4j.properties

Extract from build.xml :

```xml
<target name="createForDEV">
  <delete file="environnement/DEV/${timeStampDay}/${warfile}.war" />
  <war destfile="environnement/DEV/${timeStampDay}/${warfile}.war" webxml="environnement/DEV/web.xml" update="true">
    <classes dir="build/classes" />
    <fileset dir="WebContent">
      <exclude name="WEB-INF/web.xml" />
      <exclude name="**/Thumbs.db" />
    </fileset>
  </war>
</target>
<target name="createForINT">
  <delete file="environnement/INT/${timeStampDay}/${warfile}.war" />
  <war destfile="environnement/INT/${timeStampDay}/${warfile}.war" webxml="environnement/INT/web.xml" update="true">
    <classes dir="build/classes" />
    <fileset dir="WebContent">
      <exclude name="WEB-INF/web.xml" />
      <exclude name="**/Thumbs.db" />
      <exclude name="**/test.jsp" />
    </fileset>
  </war>
</target>
```

I have two configuration files :

- for DEV environment
- for INT environment

When I make the WAR file, I would like to ignore some files and replace them by others specific files from 'environnement' directory ?

- When making WAR in `createForDEV` target, I would like to take file from environnement/DEV and replace corresponding files
- When making WAR in `createForINT` target, I would like to take file from environnement/INT and replace corresponding files

Comment: Is it your intention to not hardcode the overriding file names in the target?  That is, whatever files happen to be in `DEV` or `INT` should overwrite the ones from `WebContent`?

Comment: @barnesjd Have you any solution even if I hardcode the overrinding file name in each target ?

Comment: You don't have to hardcode if you don't want.  I'll post the solution shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to utilize the `duplicate` attribute of the `war` task, and to include multiple `fileset` elements.  The value `preserve` for `duplicate` tells it to ignore duplicate entries.  The files in the first `fileset` (from either `DEV` or `INT`) will be placed in the war first.  Any additional files in `WebContent` will be included by the second `fileset`, but any files already included from `DEV` or `INT` will be ignored.

```
<target name="createForDEV">
  <delete file="environnement/DEV/${timeStampDay}/${warfile}.war" />
  <war destfile="environnement/DEV/${timeStampDay}/${warfile}.war" webxml="environnement/DEV/web.xml" update="true" duplicate="preserve">
    <classes dir="build/classes" />
    <fileset dir="environnement/DEV">
      <exclude name="web.xml" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="WebContent">
      <exclude name="WEB-INF/web.xml" />
      <exclude name="**/Thumbs.db" />
    </fileset>
  </war>
</target>
<target name="createForINT">
  <delete file="environnement/INT/${timeStampDay}/${warfile}.war" />
  <war destfile="environnement/INT/${timeStampDay}/${warfile}.war" webxml="environnement/INT/web.xml" update="true" duplicate="preserve">
    <classes dir="build/classes" />
    <fileset dir="environnement/INT">
      <exclude name="web.xml" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="WebContent">
      <exclude name="WEB-INF/web.xml" />
      <exclude name="**/Thumbs.db" />
      <exclude name="**/test.jsp" />
    </fileset>
  </war>
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer but it does not work as I want. For example, log4j.properties file is not going in the right directory in the WAR. It is copied in ${warfile}.war/log4j.properties and I need it in ${warfile}.war/WEB-INF/log4j.properties

Comment: OK... In fact, `environnement/XXX` directories have to have the same tree filesystem. It works if, for example, log4j.properties is like `environnement/XXX/WEB-INF/log4j.properties`. Thanks again !